# Not a valid windows embedded compact setup file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce, cab

I have developed an app for my handheld device. The handheld device is running Windows Embedded Compact 7 OS. I developed the app using VS 2008 professional C#. I chose the smart device project and target platform as Windows CE. I built the cab file and loaded it into the handheld device and tried to install it, but it told me `not a valid windows embedded compact setup file`. What is the problem with my cab file or the project settings?

[image]

Comment: What is the device model code? Some of the WEC7 devices come with a x86 processor, some with an Arm or XScale. The vendors should supply a BSP (VS addition) to be included in Visual Studio to access there model in the correct way. If there is no BSP addon available, you may choose another, generic, WEC7 SDK/BSP.

Comment: No problem with processor architecture if you're developing with .NET compact framework. I never built CAB files. Do you really need it? Why dont't you just compile and deploy the exe?